# unbind children from click for accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I have an accordion menu that I've written for SharePoint:

```
parent.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var childUL = $(this).closest("li").find("> ul");
    var isVisible = childUL.is(":visible");

    if($(e.target).hasId("#zz12_V4QuickLaunchMenu ul > ul > li > a")){
    e.stopPropagation();
     }
    else if (isVisible) {
        childUL.slideUp();
    } else {
        childUL.slideDown();
    }
});
```

The issue I'm running into is with the parent `<li>`'s.  If the parent list-item has a url, I have to utilize `preventDefault` to ensure that the `onClick` event doesn't fire as normal so that the submenu displays.  However, I'm finding that because I have **prevent default** activated, all the links essentially slide up/down when you click on them versus firing the normal click event.  I can't figure out where/how to implement the unbind event.

[jsfiddle updated.](https://jsfiddle.net/m30nar2p/7/)

EDIT:  Based on the answer below, I found the structure I needed and was able to stopPropagation.  However, it stops it for the entirety of the function.  Can someone please aid me in figuring out the correct selector?   Not familiar with nodename as suggested below and as this is nested in SharePoint's five million css classes. I'd like to use a selector that is direct as possible.  Please write actual examples if you feel so inclined to help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- identify if the click is on a link in a submenu
- if it is, apply `event.stopPropagation();`

Then, links in submenus will behave like normal links.

---

**Further Reading:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: so i'm assuming i'd have to define another local variable for target, then do an else if statement.. check if the target is the childUL variable and then tell it to stop propogation?  just making sure i'm on the right track.  thanks.

Comment: whoops wouldn't let me put jsfiddle.. but i have everything setup & tested how to stop propagation. however, i can't seem to figure out how to check if the submenu has links probably.   https://jsfiddle.net/m30nar2p/6/

Comment: You can check if the nodeName of the element being clicked on is 'A' and if the element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName is 'LI'.